# jquery / Jquery UI : Make a div appear and change an image then do the opposite

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html

Here is what I want to do :

I would like to make a web page with title, under them put a little "+" image which would onclick wrap a div containing details linked with the title. Also I want it to switch the "+" image onclick to a "-" new image and then if my user click on this new picture the opposite effect happens, the div disappear wrapping up, and the image switch back to the "+" picture.

So basicaly I use Jquery/JqueryUI in order to use the hide() and show() functions, and I picked up the Blind effect to obtain the wanted effect.

Here is my code but, it just wrap down the div, then the opposite effect does not work. Any solution ?

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".expla").hide();
    $(".grinder img").bind('click',function () {
        if($('.grinder').hasClass('plus'))
        {
            $('.grinder img').replaceWith('<img src="image/minus.png" />');
            $('.expla.egrinder').show("blind", 5000);   
            $('.grinder').removeClass('plus');


        }
        else    
        {
            $('.grinder img').replaceWith('<img src="image/add.png" />');
            $('.expla.egrinder').hide("blind", 5000);
            $('.grinder').addClass('plus');
        }
    });
})
```

Here is my HTML code :

```
 <div id="grinder">
                <div class="title grinder plus"><p>Grinder<br /><img src="image/add.png" /></p></div>
                <div class="expla egrinder"><img src="image/grinder.png" /></div>
            </div>
            <div id="flyer">
                <div class="title flyer plus"><p>Flyer<br /><img src="image/add.png" /></p></div>
                <div class="expla eflyer"><img src="image/flyer.png" /></div>
            </div>
            <div id="whack">
                <div class="title whack plus"><p>WHack<br /><img src="image/add.png" /></p></div>
                <div class="expla ewhack"><img src="image/whack.png" /></div>

            </div>
```

Well I can't answer my own question yet but here is the solution I obtain thanks to Paresh Balar :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".expla").hide();


    $(".grinder img").click(function () {
        if($('.grinder').hasClass('plus'))
        {
            $('.grinder img').attr({src: "image/minus.png" });
            $('.expla.egrinder').show("blind", 5000);   
            $('.grinder').removeClass('plus');


        }
        else    
        {
            $('.grinder img').attr({src: "image/add.png" });

            $('.expla.egrinder').hide("blind", 5000);
            $('.grinder').addClass('plus');


        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to slide down and up DIV..

see this Demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/JLy3t/